# Does an Abelian group under multiplication modulo $n$ contain $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I read the following definition in a notebook.

> The set $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{n}$ that consists of all integers $i = 0, 1, ..., n-1$ for which the $\operatorname{gcd}(i, n) = 1$ forms an *abelian* group under the binary operation multiplicaiton modulo $n$. The identity element, of course, is $1$.

But I think it should be,

> The set $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{n}$ that consists of all integers $i = 1, ..., n-1$ for which the $\operatorname{gcd}(i, n) = 1$ forms an *abelian* group under the binary operation multiplicaiton modulo $n$. The identity element, of course, is $1$.

Or could it be that both the definition are valid?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  $0$ wouldn't have an inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid. Note that $\operatorname{gcd}(0,n)=n\ne1$ (for $n>1$; but this is not serious restriction). Hence $0$ is excluded anyways.

Comment: Hmm, but if "0 is excluded anyways" (as you pointed out), then won't it be contradictory to say that the set consists of "all integers i=0, 1, ..., n-1" (as the textbook says)?

Comment: @DaveIdito Careful; it consists of "all integers $i=0,1,...,n-1$ **for which** the $\operatorname{gcd}(i,n)=1$". Take $n=4$ and $i=2$ to see that's this does not include all these integers necessarily.

Comment: @DaveIdito there's no difference if you add the given restriction "for which $\gcd(i,n)=1$" (provided $n>1$). For instance, with $n=8$, we do not talak about all the integers $i=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ either, but only of all of these that are odd.

Comment: No that's not contradictory. On the contrary you have to include $0$ here if you want the statement to be valid for $n=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Got it!

Comment: @DaveIdito Glad to help! Make sure to accept the answer if you've no further questions.